# Channel Audio from AVPlayer to SCNAudioPlayer to achieve Positional Audio

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, scenekit, avaudioplayer

I have an `AVPlayer` playing a video with sound as an `SCNMaterialProperty` on an SCNNode’s geometry in SceneKit. The video’s audio plays as expected, just non-positionally.

How can I channel just it’s audio into an `AVAudioPlayer` and add that with `addAudioPlayer:` to the `SCNNode` to achieve positional audio for that video?

Or simply, how can I achieve positional audio for that video?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No. To accomplish this is far more involved than it should be. You working with AR by any chance?

Comment: Yep. I see some potential in the MTAudioProcessingTap and then the AVAudioNode version of SCNAudioSource but way too much effort for the current project (and budget)